# How to get selection changed notification in QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to figure this out and it seems like I have to use QItemSelectionModel but I can't find an example how to wire things up.

I have defined in .h file.

```
QItemSelectionModel* selectionModel;
```

Now in constructor of the view, I set:

```
selectionModel = ui->treeView->selectionModel();

// the following line is not compiling!
connect(ui->treeView->selectionModel(), SIGNAL( ui->treeView->selectionModel(const QModelIndex&, const QModelIndex &) ),
        this, this->selectionChanged ( QItemSelection & sel,  QItemSelection & desel) );
```

I thought there would be predefined slot but I can't find one so I added this one (the syntax of which I found [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html))

```
void MyDialog::selectionChanged(const QItemSelection &selected, const QItemSelection &deselected)
{
    qDebug() << "Item selection changed";
}
```

I also tried replacing QItemSelection with QModelIndex but still doesn't work.

What do I need to do in order to simply get notified when selection has changed and than obviously grab the newly selected item?

Comment: `ui->treeView->selectionModel` is not a `SIGNAL`, or am I blind ?

Comment: I know, I copied this line and also most others line from other posts I could find :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the [QObject::connect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect) method should be used as follow :

```
QObject::connect(sender, SIGNAL(signal_method), receiver, SLOT(slot_method));
```

so in your case it should be something like

```
connect(selectionModel, SIGNAL(selectionChanged(const QItemSelection&,const QItemSelection&)), this, SLOT(mySelectionChanged(const QItemSelection&,const QItemSelection&)));
```

Comment: thanks its working but how do I get QModelIndex from QItemSelection in the handler? I am showing QFileSystemModel in tree and need to grab the newly selected file name etc

Comment: [Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselection.html#indexes) has [one of](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#QModelIndexList-typedef) the most famously [good API](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#the-foreach-keyword) documentation

Comment: Last version (5.x) of QT documentation: [QObject::connect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) .